# How to change rotation direction in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js and having trouble finding documentation on how to change rotation direction. The current rotation is set so the sphere looks like it's spinning towards the viewer on a screen but I want it to rotate in a clockwise direction, so it looks like it's spinning from a side view if a viewer is looking at it.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 500 / 400, 1, 1000);


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(500, 400);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
scene.add(cube);



camera.position.z = 10;
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
        cube.rotation.x -= 0.10;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.00;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SF9tX/1968/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then rotation around different directions (or axis') can be achieved by incrementing different components of the objects rotation vector.

So for example, if you want to rotate the cube around the y-axis (ie to create a "spinning globe" effect) you can increment the `.y` component of the `.rotation` vector, as follows:

```
var render = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // This was casuing rotation around about the x-axis
    // cube.rotation.x -= 0.10; 

    // Add this to cause rotation around the z-axis, 
    cube.rotation.z += 0.10;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Comment: Hi! 
Sorry I wasn't clear. The spinning globe effect is not what I want. I want it to look like as if there is a ball rolling across a floor but you are looking at it from the side. The original code is like as if a ball was rolling towards you instead.

So with the original code as my reference, I assume I would either need to add code in there to change the camera orientation so it pans around to the left and keep the rotation code intact or change the axis rotation so I'm "turning the ball" 45 degrees on the x axis plane to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. It's as simple as replacing the cube.rotation.x to cube.rotation.z, so:

```
camera.position.z = 10;
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
            cube.rotation.z -= 0.10;
   cube.rotation.y += 0.00;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```